# Find 4 points that form a square from 2D list

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a 2D list below:

```
a = [[3, 10], [7, 11], [7, 12], [8, 11], [8, 12], [12, 8], [12, 9], [13, 8], [13, 9], [14, 6], [14, 7], [15, 8], [17, 6], [18, 6]]
```

There are 4 points that can form a square:

```
[7, 11], [7, 12], [8, 11], [8, 12]
```

or this:

```
[12, 8], [12, 9], [13, 8], [13, 9]
```

This is my code:

```
def find_square(a):
    i = 0
    result = []
    while(i < len(a)):
        if a[i][0] == a[i + 1][0]:
            if a[i][1] == a[i + 2][1]:
                if a[i + 2][0] == a[i + 3][0]:
                    if a[i + 1][1] == a[i + 3][1]:
                        result.append([a[i][0] + 1, a[i][1] + 1])
                    i += 4
                else:
                    i += 3
            else:
                i += 2
        else:
            i += 1
    return result
```

Output:

```
[8, 12], [13, 9]
```

This code will return the last point (bottom right) of the square. I want to check if there are exist 4 points that can form a square with the side of 1 and return the bottom right point. What is a better way to implement this code?

The 2D list is assumed to be sorted in ascending order of x-coordinate.

**Update:**

I found a case that my code has a problem:

```
[7, 11], [7, 12], [7, 13], [8, 11], [8, 12]
```

The point `[7, 13]` make my code cannot detect the square.

Comment: So the square must be formed by consecutive points, not just any four points in the list?

Comment: @MOehm must be formed by consecutive points

Comment: In terms of complexity you can't really do better (this is linear, you can't do better. At best maybe you could win a constant factor). Is your question about implementation, and having nice code ?

Comment: @gdelab yes, my question is how to my code looks nicer

Comment: Technically there is a problem in your code with empty squares : suppose all your points are (0, 0) for instance. Only 1 every 4 squares will be selected. Is that fine by you, or do you want all of them, or none of them ?

Comment: @gdelab I didn't thing about that case. Thank you. I don't need any of them, maybe return 0 for that case

Comment: Also, it seems to me that you're currently detecting rectangles, not squares

Comment: @gdelab my code also has a problem that when there is a case: `[7, 11], [7, 12], [7, 13], [8, 11], [8, 12]`. the point `[7, 13]` will locate in the middle and my code can detect the square

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, maybe something like this:

```
def find_square(a):
    result = []
    for (bl, tl, br, tr) in zip(a, a[1:], a[2:], a[3:]):
        if bl[0] == tl[0] and br[0] == tr[0] and \
           bl[1] == br[1] and tl[1] == tr[1] and \
           br[0] - bl[0] == tl[1] - bl[1]:
           result.append(tr)
    return result
```

The names of the variables are `bl` for bottom left, `tl` for top left, `br` for bottom right, and `tr` for top right corner. On the first line of `if` we check the `x` coordinates, on the second line - check the `y` coordinates, on the third line we check that it's a square, not a rectangle.

**UPDATED for the new condition**

```
def find_square(a):  
    d = {}
    for p1, p2 in zip(a, a[1:]):
        if p2[0] == p1[0] and p2[1] == p1[1] + 1:
            d.setdefault(p1[1], []).append(p1[0])
    result = []
    for y, xs in d.items():
        for x1, x2 in zip(xs, xs[1:]):
            if x2 == x1 + 1:
                result.append([x2, y + 1])
    return result
```

Explanation: first we go through  the array and look for points, which have another point just above them. If we find such a point, then we add a new value to the dictionary `d`. The key is a vertical coordinate, and the value will contain list of possible `x` coordinates. In the next loop we just go through each of these lists of `x` coordinates and check if the list contains two consecutive `x` coordinates. If it does, then we have found a square.

Comment: Your code is implemented nicer than me, but we have the same problem with the case that I've just found. I ran this case `[7, 11], [7, 12], [7, 13], [8, 11], [8, 12]` with your code and it doesn't return `[8, 12]`

Comment: Oh, you edited your question. You added this case, but in your question there are still words 'consecutive points'. In your example there are **no** consecutive points making a square. So you need either to remove word 'consecutive' or don't consider this example.

Comment: Consecutive points mean `7` to `8`, `11` to `12`. The length of the square is `1`.

Comment: So they can be anywhere in the initial list, but the square size has to be 1 ? This changes everything

Comment: Can they also be in any order in the list ?

Comment: @gdelab the list is sorted in ascending order with x coordinate. In other words, the first element of sub-list

Comment: @dhuy Updated to match the new condition.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that does not require the points to be consecutive, or even the list to be sorted in any way :

```
a = [[3, 10], [7, 11], [7, 12], [7, 13], [8, 11], [8, 12], [12, 8], [12, 9], [13, 8], [13, 9], [14, 6], [14, 7], [15, 8], [17, 6], [18, 6]]

from itertools import combinations

def is_square(points, square_side=1):
    if len(set(tuple(pt) for pt in points)) != 4:  # Some points are identical
        return False
    x_coords = sorted(set(pt[0] for pt in points))
    y_coords = sorted(set(pt[1] for pt in points))
    if not (len(x_coords) == len(y_coords) == 2):  # Points are not aligned 2 by 2 on x and on y
        return False
    # We now know we have a rectangle
    if not (x_coords[1] - x_coords[0] == y_coords[1] - y_coords[0] == square_side):
        # Not a square, or not the right size
        return False
    return True

def find_square(pts_list, square_side=1):
    result = []
    for pts in combinations(pts_list, 4):
        if is_square(pts, square_side):  # Retrieve the right point
            result.append([max(pt[0] for pt in pts), max(pt[1] for pt in pts)])
    return result

print(find_square(a, 1))
```

It is however in `Theta(N⁴)`, whereas using the fact that the list is sorted by `x`, with only integer coordinates, and that the square size has to be 1, there is a solution in `Theta(N²)` at worst and even `Theta(N)` in average (see [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60833134/7456923)).

Comment: Unfortunately this solution has complexity of O(N^4), while with sorted input it's possible to do in O(N^2) in the worst case, O(N) in the best.

Comment: yes you're right (if the indices are all integers, which seems to be the case). Nice solution !